# Why are there flakes in my beer after 5 days?

Tags: fermentation

I am currently brewing my first batch of beer and I have been checking on the temperature every day. Up until now the top of the beer looked normal and was fermenting as I expect. Today however, I looked at the top of it and most of the heaviness was gone which was replaced by what looked like flakes. Is this normal after 5 days?

[image]

Comment: A photograph would be a nice addition to this question.

Comment: @NathanKoop I thought about that, but it may be hard to see in a picture. I will try though and get back on here.

Comment: @NathanKoop I added a picture. Does that help?

Comment: OH no! you used flash! your brew is ruined! lol jk jk, i had something that looked very similar in a recent brew. All turned out fine, I assume it is yeast floaties :) mmmmmmm

Comment: @Michael I actually used a flash light on the container and took the picture without flash lol. The flash was causing the picture to only see the outside of the container. Thanks for your comment, that makes me feel a little better about it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most often when I see flakes in primary they are hops particles. If that's what it is, they will settle out over time. When you siphon for bottling or secondary most of them will be left behind.

By the way, I would strongly suggest NOT opening the fermentation chamber every day. You risk infection every time you open it. Just leave it alone for at least a week (preferably two) and monitor temperature with an external temp strip.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the explanation! I have not been opening it, just looking through the keg. It is a beginners kit from Mr. Beer, so its a plastic keg that is see through.

Comment: That also brings up another question. I have the temperature strip like you said, is that strip always a few degrees below the internal temperature?

Comment: I think the strips are pretty accurate within a degree or two of the temp of the beer. The big difference you often see is that the temp of the air can be as much as 10 degrees cooler than the temp of the carboy, because fermentation creates heat.

Comment: I added a picture. I wanted to verify that this is correct before I accept it.

Comment: It's difficult to say from your picture. It could be 'yeast floaties' too. Regardless, I doubt it's anything to worry about (unless they start to look fuzzy and get bigger like mold).

Comment: Yeah I figured it was going to be hard to take a picture without the light reflecting. Thanks for your help, I will message back on here when its done if it all came out okay!